# Java JWT Docusign API - Redirect

Tags: docusignapi

I have opted for Embedded Signing and JWT Token . I have created the RecipientView and I am getting a valid url to do the embedded signing. But this url is getting redirected internally to this url "https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/StartInSession.aspx?code=..." and it is neither allowing me to sign nor redirecting to the redirect url of my application.

I have tried the same with Authorization Code Grant but it works perfectly.

Please do let me know what changes must be done to get it working

Comment: Hey Aneena. Are you following this guide on the Developer Center? https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken

Answer (score 0):

When you say not "allowing me to sign" what is happening? Are you seeing the envelope and its documents?

Is the signer recipient someone other than yourself?

Since it's all working with auth code grant, it sounds like the sender/signers are conflated.